# Connection reset by peer for getstream.io python client

Tags: python, getstream-io

The following python code returns a `'(Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))`. All I want to do is post something to this persons timeline.

```py
client = stream.connect(STREAM_API_KEY, STREAM_KEY_SECRET)

# For the feed group 'user' and user id get the feed
user_feed = client.feed('timeline', user_id)

try:
   # Add the activity to the feed
   user_feed.add_activity({'actor': user_id, 'verb': 'tweet', 'object': 1, 'tweet': 'Hello world'})
except Exception as e:
   print('Failed to add activity to stream for user_id: {}'.format(user_id))
```

Comment: how often do you get this error?

Comment: Every time I make the call

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli - Running locally this occurs every time. If I run this code on my AWS account it runs fine. I'm running locally on Python 3 on a Mac.

Comment: check your DNS setup, perhaps give 8.8.8.8 a try and see if that solves the problem